# How to set content type for @SpringBootTest

Tags: spring-boot

I have a SpringBootTest class which uses SpringRunner:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment= SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.DEFINED_PORT)
public class DemoApplicationTests {

    @Test
    public void testCustomerList() {

        get("http://localhost:8080/list")
                .then()
                .assertThat()
                .statusCode(200)
                .body("size()", is(2));



    }

}
```

I'd like to change the accept header for the test, much like I'd do with curl:

```
curl --header "Accept: application/json" curl http://localhost:8080
```

I've tried with:

```
get("http://localhost:8080/list").contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
```

However I get the error "ContentType cannot be applied to Response options".
Can you recommend a way to fix it?
Thanks!

Comment: You should have `.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)`

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the `accept` header.

```
    get("http://localhost:8080/list")
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
            .then()
            .assertThat()
            .statusCode(200)
            .body("size()", is(2));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add accept header using `accept` method:

```
.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
```

See also [accept vs content type](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/31212/difference-between-the-accept-and-content-type-http-headers)

> Accept header is used by HTTP clients to tell the server what content types they'll accept. The server will then send back a response, which will include a Content-Type header telling the client what the content type of the returned content actually is

Answer (score 0):

Seems I've figured it out.
As *get* is **io.restassured.RestAssured.get** (my apologies for not specifying it),
then it should be:

```
given()
.contentType("application/json").
.get("http://localhost:8080/list")
```